# Doing drop and this msg appear: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

so Im using this statement to delete from my df some value with multiple conditions.

```
Delete = df[ (df['Food'] == 'Ham') & (df['Fruit'] == 'Beans') ].index
df.drop(Delete, inplace=True)
```

and I'm getting the message "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

I investigated and it seems I'm not doing the change in the original data frame, how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `df[ ~((df['Food'] == 'Ham') & (df['Fruit'] == 'Beans') )]`

Comment: whats the "~" for?

Comment: like ~True is False